# Removing repeated characters, including spaces, in one line

Tags: regex, perl

I currently have a string, say `$line='55.25040882,     3,,,,,,'`, that I want to remove all whitespace and repeated commas and periods from. Currently, I have:

```
    $line =~ s/[.,]{2,}//;
    $line =~ s/\s{1,}//;
```

Which works, as I get `'55.25040882,3'`, but when I try

```
$line =~ s/[.,\s]{2,}//;
```

It pulls out the ",     " and leaves the ",,,,,,". I want to retain the first comma and just get rid of the whitespace. 
Is there a way to elegantly do this with one line of regex? Please let me know if I need to provide additional information.

EDIT: Since there were so many solutions, I decided to update my question with the answer below:

```
$line =~ s/([.,])\1{1,}| |\t//g;
```

This removes all repeated periods and commas, removes all spaces and tabs, while retaining the \r and \n characters. There are so many ways to do this, but this is the one I settled for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using: -

```
my $line='55.25040...882, 3,,,,,,';
$line =~ s/[^\S\n\r]|[.,]{2,}//g;  # Negates non-whitespace char, \n and \r
print $line
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
55.25040882,3
```

- `[^\S\n\r]|[.,]{2,}` -> This means either `[^\S\n\r]` or `[.,]{2,}`
- `[.,]{2,}` -> This means replace `,` or `.` if there is more than `2` in the same
  line.
- `[^\S\n\r]` ->  Means negate all `whitespace character`, linefeed, and newline.

Comment: Updated Regex, to consider periods also. Missed that.

Comment: This one seems to remove \r and \n, as well. It does work well otherwise, however!!

Comment: @Thumper Updated Regex to consider `\r` and `\n`

Comment: This also works for me: $line =~ s/([.,])\1{1,}| //g;
Both you and @acheong87 really helped me with your replies. I am also trying to understand how regex works. Trying your last solution, as well.

Comment: Try this : $line =~ s/[^\S\n\r]|[.,]{2,}//g;

It will match all whitespace except \n and \r

Comment: @Shashwat Aw! That is far better. Will post it.

Comment: Well, I derived my original solution from acheong87, but yours also works... I wish I could choose two.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the problem. Doesn't your solution remove _all_ commas (or _all_ periods) in a chain of commas/periods? I thought the asker wanted to keep the first instance.

Comment: @acheong87. No the question asked to keep the first comma in the pattern OP posted. See, he posted the expected output also. His first means the first comma.. See `as I get '55.25040882,3'`

Comment: This, and Alan Moore's responses have really helped me better-understand regex. Wow. I can't thank either of you enough for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly a critique of [Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877163/20938), which seems to contain several misconceptions about character class syntax, especially the negation operator (`^`).  Specifically:

- `[(^\n^\r)\s]` matches `(` or `^` or `)` or any whitespace character, *including* linefeed (`\n`) and carriage return (`\r`).  In fact, they're each specified twice (since `\s` matches them too), though the class still only consumes one character at a time.
- `^[\n\r]|\s` matches a linefeed or carriage return at the beginning of the string, or any whitespace character anywhere (which makes the first part redundant, since *any whitespace character* includes linefeed and carriage return, and *anywhere* includes the beginning of the string).

Inside a character class, the caret (`^`) negates the meaning of everything that follows **iff** it appears immediately after the opening `[`; anywhere else, it's just a caret.  All other metacharacters except `\` lose their special meanings entirely inside character classes.  (But the normally non-special characters, `-` and `]`, become special.)

Outside a character class, `^` is an anchor.

---

Here's how I would write the regex:

```
$line =~ s/([.,])\1+|\h+//g;
```

Explanation:

- Since you finally went with `([.,])\1{1,}`, I assume you want to match *repeated periods* or *repeated commas*, not things like `.,` or `,.`.  Success with regexes means learning to look at text the way the regex engine does, and it's not intuitive.  You'll help yourself a lot if you try to describe each problem the way the regex engine would, if it could speak.
- `{1,}` is not incorrect, but why add all that clutter to your regex when `+` does the same thing?
- `\h` matches *horizontal* whitespace, which includes spaces and tabs, but not linefeeds or carriage returns.  (That only works in Perl, AFAIK.  In Ruby/Oniguruma, `\h` matches a hex digit; in every other flavor I know of, it's a syntax error.)

Comment: @AlanMoore.. I didn't noticed that was happening in my regex. Actually that worked for me for the first time, so posted it.. I have edited it, to remove the wrong Regex. Can you take a look and comment whether it is correct or not??

Comment: @RohitJain: `[^\S\r\n]` is probably good enough, but I'd use something more accurate and readable, like `[\x20\t]` or `\h`.  As for `[.,]{2,}`, it matches jumbles of periods and commas, where I believe the OP wants pure runs of one or the other.